# understanding en fixing the error in DSolve system

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, physics, code-review, event-detection

Why does this code not work:

```
vi[t] = 230*Sqrt[2]*Sin[2*Pi*50*t];
vr[t] = Abs[vi[t]];
system = {vo'[t] == 
    charging[t] vr'[t] - (1 - charging[t]) vo[t]/(r c), vo[0] == 0};
control = {charging[0] == 1, WhenEvent[vr'[t] < 0, charging[t] -> 0], 
  WhenEvent[And[vo[t] < vr[t], charging[t] == 0, vr'[t] > 0], 
   charging[t] -> 1]}; pars = {r -> 0.1, c -> 1};
sol = DSolve[{system, control} /. pars, vo, {t, 0, Infinity}, 
   DiscreteVariables -> charging \[Element] {0, 1}];
```

I get the following error:

> DSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of WhenEvent[(vr^[Prime])[t]<0,charging[t]->0] in the first argument {{(vo^[Prime])[t]==charging[t] Piecewise[{{<<2>>}},23000 Power[<<2>>] [Pi] Cos[<<1>>]]-10. (1-charging[<<1>>]) vo[t],vo[0]==0},{charging[0]==1,WhenEvent[(vr^[Prime])[t]<0,charging[t]->0],WhenEvent[vo[t]0,charging[t]->1]}}. >>

But I do not understand why I can't use this code. Can someone help me how I can fix it.

Comment: First you should correct the definitions `vi[t],vr[t]` to something like `vi[t_] := ...,vi[t_] := ...`. Secontly DSolve can't handle the function `charging[t]`: Did you define it elsewhere ? Or do you want to solve a DAE system?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes I want to solve a DAE system

Comment: So you should defiine charging inside DSolve as dependent variabel  as you did with v0 (not` Discrete...`).